# Adapter doesn't response after popping an AleartDialog from another fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Hello guys I am for first time here so if there are some mistakes with my problem just notify me to correct my self. My problem is in the adapter I think. My application is with 3 fragment tabs. In each tab I have a ListView with some items. Also I have button in each tab that updates,deletes or adds items. I make that by popping up an AleartDialog for adding a new item or clicking on the item from the list to update it or delete it. So after I login in my application I can do what ever I want with that list. Its not a problem. I can rotate the screen and my list still updates. Changing the tabs its not a problem also. The problem comes when I go to other fragment I click on the button for adding  or on some of the items for updating  and the AleartDialog pops up. After that when I close it I return to the first tab. Trying to add an item doesn't update the list and I see the same items. Deleting the item from the list then throws exception IndexOutOfBounds because the item its not in the list. I think I use `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` properly. Here I will share some other code.

Like that I update my list. In the jsonObject is list the with the items.

```
private void fillList(Gson gson, String jsonObject) {
listWithNames.clear();
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<PersonalSaveDTO>>() {
}.getType();

personalSaveList = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, collectionType);
Log.wtf(TAG, "OT REQUEST: " + personalSaveList);
  for (int i = 0; i < personalSaveList.size(); i++) {
    listWithNames.add(personalSaveList.get(i).getName());
  }
  Log.wtf(TAG, "fillList: " + listWithNames);
  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      buttonEnable(true);
    }
  });
}
```

Like that I starts the fragment.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                       Bundle savedInstanceState) {

final View viewFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_fragment, container, false);
listViewUser = (ListView) viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.listViewForUser);
addItem = (Button) viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddUserElements);
updateList = (Button) viewFragment.findViewById(R.id.refreshListUser);
updateList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    makeRequestForList(viewFragment);
  }
});
addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    addElement(viewFragment);
  }
});
configureArrayAdapter(viewFragment);
setListenerForUserList(viewFragment);
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
  isRequestMade = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isRequestMade");
  listWithNames = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("listWithNames");
  personalSaveList = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("personalSaveList");
  arrayAdapter.addAll(listWithNames);
  arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

if (!isRequestMade) {
  makeRequestForList(viewFragment);
  isRequestMade = true;
}
return viewFragment;
```

}

And here is how I create the adapter.

```
  private void configureArrayAdapter(View view) {
listWithNames = new ArrayList<>();
arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(),
    R.layout.list_personal_group_fragment, R.id.adapterFragmentPersonalGroups, listWithNames);
arrayAdapter.clear();
listViewUser.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```